# Possible encoding issue with Google PubSub

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, google-cloud-pubsub, alpakka

When running a subscription source from the Alpakka PubSub library I received possible encoded data.

```scala
@Singleton
class Consumer @Inject()(config: Configuration, credentialsService: google.creds.Service)(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem) {

  implicit val m: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer.create(actorSystem)
  val logger = Logger(this.getClass)
  val subName: String = config.get[String]("google.pubsub.subname")
  val credentials: Credentials = credentialsService.getCredentials
  val pubSubConfig = PubSubConfig(credentials.projectId, credentials.clientEmail, credentials.privateKey)

  val subSource: Source[ReceivedMessage, NotUsed] = GooglePubSub.subscribe(subName, pubSubConfig)
  val ackSink: Sink[AcknowledgeRequest, Future[Done]] = GooglePubSub.acknowledge(subName, pubSubConfig)

  val computeGraph = Flow[ReceivedMessage].map {
    x =>
      logger.info(x.message.data)
      x
  }

  val ackGraph = Flow.fromFunction((msgs: Seq[ReceivedMessage]) => AcknowledgeRequest(msgs.map(_.ackId).toList))

  subSource
    .via(computeGraph)
    .groupedWithin(10, 5.minutes)
    .via(ackGraph)
    .to(ackSink)
    .run()
}
```

I publish the message from the PubSub console. I am expecting my test message to appear however when publishing `test` I receive `dGVzdA==`. Is this an expected result? I have had issues with importing the private key and this might be a result of it?

The consumer is bound eagerly with Guice.

Comment: `dGVzdA==` is "test", just Base 64 encoded.

Comment: @SeanVieira why is it sending it Base 64 encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data that is received over REST apis will be [base64 encoded](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage).  My guess would be that the Alpakka Pub/Sub library which [uses the REST APIs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/google-cloud-pub-sub.html) is not properly decoding the received data.  It looks like they also have a library that uses the GRPC Pub/Sub client as the underlying layer which may not suffer from this defect?  You can also use the [Cloud Pub/Sub Java client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#pubsub-pull-messages-async-java) from Scala directly.